# How to deal with " NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: "

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

My error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotADirectoryError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-b4da6c1da6e1> in <module>
     12 lst = []
     13 for d in lst1:
---> 14     lst = lst + listdir(d)
     15 lst

<ipython-input-2-b4da6c1da6e1> in listdir(path)
      4 def listdir(path):  #传入存储的list
      5     lst = []
----> 6     for file in os.listdir(path):
      7         file_path = os.path.join(path, file)
      8         lst.append(file_path)

NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Users/zhangzhenzhi/Desktop/Term2_Final/CASA0006/CityofLondonCrimeData/.DS_Store'
```

And my code is

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-  
import os  

def listdir(path):  #传入存储的list
    lst = []
    for file in os.listdir(path):  
        file_path = os.path.join(path, file)  
        lst.append(file_path) 
    return lst
lst1 = listdir(r'/Users/zhangzhenzhi/Desktop/Term2_Final/CASA0006/CityofLondonCrimeData' )

lst = []
for d in lst1:
    lst = lst + listdir(d)
lst
```

I want to save all of the files' path to a listm, but I run it, it showed an error and i can't understand what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check type of object before "os.listdir"

```py
def listdir(path):  #传入存储的list
    lst = []
    if os.path.isdir(path): # Check this path = path to folder
        for file in os.listdir(path):  
           file_path = os.path.join(path, file)  
           lst.append(file_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the exception. 
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Users/zhangzhenzhi/Desktop/Term2_Final/CASA0006/CityofLondonCrimeData/.DS_Store'

This line
`lst1 = listdir(r'/Users/zhangzhenzhi/Desktop/Term2_Final/CASA0006/CityofLondonCrimeData' )`

This returns list of all paths including files with full path, and ".DS_Store" is a file. Then, you also loop through what you got on `lst1`. In which case `os.listdir` tries to operate on a file (the path in the traceback) which causes the exception to be thrown.

More solid way is to use package glob for that purpose. Try

`glob.glob(path)` and it returns the list of paths under that path. If you want it to be recursive add `/**` to the end of the path and add `recursive=True` parameter.